# Google Colab cv.ocl.haveOpenCL() False

Tags: opencv, opencl, gpu, google-colaboratory

Google Colab's version of opencv-python has OpenCL support:

```
  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /io/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load
```

But `cv.ocl.haveOpenCL()` returns False. I'm assuming because an OCL runtime is not installed.

Is there any way to use OpenCL on Google Colab's GPU accelerated environment?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Runtime -> Change runtime type -> Select: Hardware Accelerator (GPU)

And try:

```
print(cv2.ocl.haveOpenCL()) # returns true
```